# Google Tag Manager - Product with multiple categories

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm developing a tag, but the product, wines, has 5 categories, like country, region, type of grape, etc...
However, the dataLayer contains a slot for only 1 category.

`'transactionProducts': [{
    'sku': 'DD44',
    'name': 'T-Shirt',
    'category': 'Apparel',
    'price': 11.99,
    'quantity': 1
}]`

I need this:

`'transactionProducts': [{
    'sku': 'DD44',
    'name': 'T-Shirt',
    'category': ['Category 1','Category 2','Category 3'],
    'price': 11.99,
    'quantity': 1
}]`

Is possible? Works correctly?

Comment: Very curious also. Did you find any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the categories into an array won't work as the field only accepts a single string. You can use a pipe (or anything)-delimited string instead:

```
'category': 'Category 1|Category 2|Category 3',
```

Comment: Wines have a difficult categorization. Your solution helps me, but Google could implement my need.
Anyway, thanks, Nyuen.